# How to sound full and present when performing outdoors?

Tags: performing

When I perform outdoors, I sound distant and thin, and I'd rather sound pretty much "in your face". How do I achieve that sound? I play with a country rock group, strong vocals, fiddles and electric guitars and drums.

Comment: What instrument do you play? Do you have an amplifier? Or a microphone? Please provide more details.

Comment: Are you singing acapella on a mountain, playing drums in the back yard? We need a lot more info.

Comment: Lots of powerful subwoofers. Actually it really can’t be done. You’ll never make outdoors sound like indoors. Personally I prefer the outdoor sound but either way sometimes a thing can’t be made anything other than what it is.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - not as bad as playing in marquees though...

Comment: What, no bass player?

Comment: We don't have marquees in American English, so I don't have to worry about that. :-)

Comment: Get better monitoring. As you cannot hear what the audience is hearing, your perception is entirely subjective. It might sound great FoH, you'll never know from on-stage.

Comment: @Tim - Please provide a short definition of what your "marquee" might be called in the states. Sounds like I'd want to avoid those gigs at all costs.

Comment: Marquees are great big tents. I used to play in them mainly for posh weddings and corporate events. Not for camping in, but to hold a few hundred people.

Comment: I've played in marquees up to about 1000 people. You just have to treat them as outdoor festivals and amp up accordingly

Comment: @Tim Ah. The AmE word for that is "tent" or possibly "circus tent". I would say one advantage they have over straight outdoors is rain coverage.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - not like a circus tent, which, by definition, is pretty well circular!  But huge tent, nevertheless, with canvas/plastic sides, which does nothing positive for the sound. It does however protect from wind and rain, unless there's a leak right above the stage area, which has happened a few times. Circuit breakers are your best friend and worst enemy at the same time then!

Comment: I would expect that the fabric walls would act the same way that curtains in a reverberant room act, but since there is little or no reverberation typically outdoors, we might sound like we are playing in an anechoic chamber. Definitely counter productive to what I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put up a wall behind you.  The audience will be in front anyway, so there is little point in blasting out your behind.  Stand on a stage with a hard floor: no need to make the ground shake: just brings out the earthworms.

The neighbors will also appreciate if you can deal out your sound energy more focused on the audience since then it will not be as loud outside of audience coverage.  So basically you need a stage with a floor and back panels.

Comment: So the answer to playing outdoors is 'build a room'  :-)

Comment: @ Laurence Payne- Perhaps a rental orchestra Shell and good monitors if the price is right.

Answer (score 1):

You've got used to the sound being reinforced by bouncing off the walls of a room.  Outside, that won't happen - though you might get a slap echo if there's a wall or building in the vicinity.

You can turn the bass up.  Add some reverb.  Surround the audience with PA speakers rather than just having a couple set up at the front.

If you do home recording, learn the lesson of how much you're hearing the particular ROOM you're in while mixing.